# Volume controls not working on Lumia 920

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, buttons, volume, sound, headset

So I decided to put in headphones into my audio jack and my music played fine but kept making this screeching noise. It wasn't my headphones cause I put it into my tablet and it didn't do it, then my music two says later on Xbox music said there was an error code and my sound doesn't work and the sound bar that usually pops up pressing the volume buttons doesn't come down all the way. Neither does my YouTube music, it says there's been an internet time out and a zuma or something is around. Really enjoyed this phone, just wish I could fix it .any ideas?

Comment: did u try soft reset? and are u on 8.1 on 10?

Comment: @RamRaj Must be 8.1 as he mentions Xbox music instead of Groove.